# Quarkcoin's bitcoin-qt fork won't recognise unspent transaction

Tags: transactions, alternatives, confirmations, quarkcoin

I've got a problem with my bitcoin wallet client, I got around 10 QRK by mining via a pool, transferred them to my local wallet and then sent them to btc-e, I got a dialogue box saying something about the TX being too large and if I wished to add a fee, I said yes, and after that, the TX was registered in my wallet, but now two days have passed and I don't have even a single confirmation, I've searched for the TX and my address in the QRK blockchain explorers and I couldn't find a single reference to my TX.

Any ideas on how to "purge" that *fake* TX and get my coins back (they are unspent, according to the network, there should be a way to do a "rollback")?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=231309.0 worked for me, as it says:

1. Export your private key in base58 format (how to do this depends on the software used to make the unconfirmed transaction, but I'm sure it is straight-forward)
2. Create an empty wallet in bitcoin-qt (can be done with renaming your current wallet.dat to wallet.dat.bak and launching bitcoin-qt. Just be sure to keep wallet.dat.bak...)
3. Launch bitcoin-qt
4. Import the private key into bitcoin-qt (see this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys_v7%2B)
5. Quit bitcoin-qt
6. Run
   bitcoin-qt -rescan
7. Wait
8. Wait...
9. Now you have the full balance of the single key you imported (compare with blockexplorer. If not, stop here and post in this thread)
10. Create the transaction you wanted to do without forgetting the fee
11. Delete the new, nearly empty wallet.dat (just rename it if you're not sure about that part)
12. Rename wallet.dat.bak (thus your original wallet) to wallet.dat
13. Done